# WordPress SELECT with JOIN not working

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Am working on a **WORDPRESS** plugin where i need all product details, The site uses **woocommerce** plugin, and **woocomerce** stores products as posts and product meta is stored(distributed) in many other tables. I ***have to get all the products(and related details)*** anyhow. I googled and found the query below. It seems worked for others but i could not make it work.

```
global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT 
                    p.id, 
                    p.post_title, 
                    p.guid, 
                    p.post_type, 
                    m.meta_key, 
                    m.meta_value, 
                    meta_sp.meta_value as sale_price, 
                    meta_ap.meta_value as additional_price
            FROM wp_posts p
            INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m
            INNER JOIN wp_postmeta meta_sp ON p.id=meta_sp.post_id 
                AND meta_sp.meta_key='sale_price'
            INNER JOIN wp_postmeta meta_ap ON p.id=meta_ap.post_id 
                AND meta_ap.meta_key='additional_price'
            WHERE p.id=m.post_id
            AND m.meta_key='_rentable' AND m.meta_value='yes'";

        $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
        var_dump($results);

Result :  array (size=0) empty.
```

Can any one tell me **how to make the above query work**, or maybe a **way to get all products in the site db**.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an `ON`, try this:

```
SELECT 
    p.id, 
    p.post_title, 
    p.guid, 
    p.post_type, 
    m.meta_key, 
    m.meta_value, 
    meta_sp.meta_value as sale_price, 
    meta_ap.meta_value as additional_price
FROM wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m ON p.id=m.post_id 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta meta_sp ON p.id=meta_sp.post_id 
    AND meta_sp.meta_key='sale_price'
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta meta_ap ON p.id=meta_ap.post_id 
    AND meta_ap.meta_key='additional_price'
WHERE p.id=m.post_id
AND m.meta_key='_rentable' AND m.meta_value='yes'
```

Comment: Hey Benvorth, I tried your solution but its still the same
 array (size=0) empty.
 Other queries are working fine but this particular query didnt work. Please see if anything else is wrong, and thank you for the reply.